# Swiftmailer doesn't work

Tags: symfony, email, swiftmailer

I have problem with sending mails via Swiftmailer

My parameters file is:

```
parameters:
  mailer_transport: smtp
  mailer_host: mail.myweb.cz
  mailer_user: noreply@myweb.cz
  mailer_password: pass
```

If I send mail to address with any@myweb.cz, mail arrives. But if I send mail to another address, for example something@gmail.com, mail does not arrives.

SMTP on server is set:

```
server: smtp.myweb.cz
port: 587
security: STARTTLS
auth method: Normal password
```

In Thunderbird is everthing ok, mistake must be in swiftmailer config.

Thanks for help

---

EDIT:

On my local dev computer it works with solve from Javier Eguiluz, but I have an error on prod server now:

app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Unable to connect with TLS encryption.

But if I try connect to server with STARTTLS from any other computer via telnet, it works.

Do you have any idea?

---

SOLVE:

Problem was in self-signed certificate. I hadn't it in trusted certificates.

Comment: If any mail sent to myweb.cz arrives then this does not seem a problem with swiftmailer config, I think it must be some SMTP configuration which does not allow sending to outside email addresses, probably related to relay configuration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my Gmail configuration I also need to define the swiftmailer `encryption` option to `ssl`.

Maybe you should add the following to your config?

```
parameters:
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: mail.myweb.cz
    mailer_port: 587
    mailer_encryption: tls
    mailer_user: noreply@myweb.cz
    mailer_password: pass
```

And then in your `app/config/config.yml` file add those new options too:

```
swiftmailer:
    # ...
    port: %mailer_port%
    encryption: %mailer_encryption%
```

Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#encryption

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue!

Comment: On my local dev computer it works, but I have an error on prod server: `app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Unable to connect with TLS encryption`. What's wrong? :(